# how to know if a shape parameter exist

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to see if a video is linked or not using vba. For that I check the parameters of the shape and I saw that I the video is linked LinkFormat parameter is enable and if it is not is disabled. The problem is that if I check LinkFormat when it is not a linked video I get an error "Object does not exist". I just want to check if it exist or not without having an error.

I try to put an error handler but anyway it is giving me the error.

EDIT: Here I put how I am trying to make it with the advices that I receive in this post:

```
   For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides

    For i = 1 To sld.Shapes.count

       If sld.Shapes(i).Type = msoMedia Then

                If hasVideo = False Then
                    hasVideo = True
                End If
                videoNum = videoNum + 1

                     If sld.Shapes(i).MediaType = ppMediaTypeMovie Then
                        If CSng(Application.Version) < 14 Then
                            If hasVideo = False Then
                                hasVideo = True
                            End If
                            videoNum = videoNum + 1
                        Else
                            If sld.Shapes(i).MediaFormat.IsEmbedded Then
                                If hasVideo = False Then
                                    hasVideo = True
                                End If
                                videoNum = videoNum + 1
                            Else
                                MsgBox "linked videos are not supported and won't be shown"                                
                            End If
                        End If
                  End If
        End If
     Next i
   Next
```

Comment: Show your code if possible...

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub TestVideos()
    ' oSh as Object rather than as Shape so it'll work
    ' in earlier versions of PPT that don't have some of these
    ' properties
    Dim oSh As Object
    Dim oSl As Slide

    ' because my test file has two videos
    ' on slide 1 ...
    Set oSl = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)

    For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
        If oSh.Type = msoMedia Then
            If oSh.MediaType = ppMediaTypeMovie Then
                If CSng(Application.Version) < 12 Then
                    ' This is PPT 2003 or earlier; all vids are embedded
                    MsgBox "This video is embedded"
                Else
                    If oSh.MediaFormat.IsEmbedded Then
                        MsgBox "This video is embedded"
                    Else
                        MsgBox "This video is linked"
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Finally I found a powerpoint that gave me an error in those lines. It goes to else in If CSng(Application.Version) < 12 and in If oSh.MediaFormat.IsEmbedded Then it gives me an error because MediaFormat doesn't exist.

Comment: My mistake:  that should be  < 14 rather than < 12.  14 = PPT 2010, the first version to begin embedding videos.

Comment: No it didn't work... CSng(Application.Version) is 15 so it goes to else. But is linked and MediaFormat doesn't exist so it gives me an error. I copy here the MediaFormat line taken from the watch:       : MediaFormat : <Shape.MediaFormat : Object does not exist.> : MediaFormat : Module1.Button1

Comment: Here you have what I am doing. BTW I am using office 2013 in windows 8. I don't think that this matters but just in case. Thanks!

Comment: I copy/pasted your code into PPT 2013/Win8 and tried it on a slide with one video both linked and embedded.  After I dimmed all the variables, it Works fine, no errors.  Have you tried the same code on a newly created presentation?  It might be something peculiar to this presentation.