# Determine if a video is linked or not vba

Tags: vba, video, powerpoint

I am trying to see if a video is linked or not using VBA. The problem is that when the video is linked Shape.MediaFormat doesn't exist and when it is not linked Shape.MediaFormat exists but LinkFormat.SourceFullName doesn't.

So If I check MediaFormat it gives me error every time the video is linked and if I try using LinkFormat.SourceFullName it gave me an error every time it is not linked.

I need something to check if those properties exist or not without giving error.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see which one is "Nothing" before using it.

```
if Shape.MediaFormat IsNot Nothing


end if

if Shape.SourceFullName IsNot Nothing


end if
```

Comment: I try with the following If ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes(j).MediaFormat IsNot Nothing Then but it gave me a Compile error "Expected: Then of GoTo"

Comment: I have to say that I had tested with If ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes(j).MediaFormat Is Nothing Then but it also gave me an error: "Shape.MediaFormat : Object does not exist"

Answer (score 0):

The routine I posted here in response to another of your questions (and corrected today) will get you there with a few more lines of code.

[how to know if a shape parameter exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17744172/how-to-know-if-a-shape-parameter-exist/17749303?noredirect=1#comment26430591_17749303)

It tells you whether the media object is embedded or not.  If it's embedded, there'll be no LinkFormat, so don't try to access it. If it's not embedded, then it's linked; you can access LinkFormat

Comment: It didn't work... I put the comments in the other question I made but basically it checks MediaFormat witch doesn't exist.